# how to perform same DML statements on two different server ( Oracle and SQL )

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two servers ORACLE and SQL.

I have same database on both the servers .

I want to perform DML (insert,update,delete).

How can I perform same DML statements on both the servers simultaneously ?

If I insert one statement in SQL server  then the same statement should be updated in the oracle database .

Thanks

Comment: This question is *possibly* better suited for [`DBA Exchange`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 0):

you can use MS SQL (and Oracle probably has something similar) to create a linked server. 
Please refer to these links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

This basically lets you use MS SQL as usual, but you can reference a completely different system thorough this functionality.

Lets say you have the following simple table scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE Tbl
(
 ID int,
 SOMETHING NVARCHAR(100)
);
```

I wouldn't want to call two different `INSERT` statements, so I would write a stored procedure that does the inserting on my behalf.

Lets assume the stored procedure name is `SP_MyTest` and has two parameters: @ID, @SOMETHING. I would use a transaction in order to assure I always insert into both tables. 
But keep in mind - this implementation is synchronous which means: If one insert takes "forever" then the application will hold for the duration of that time unless you make some additions.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_MyTest
    @ID INT,
    @SOMETHING NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION TRN
    INSERT INTO Tbl(ID,SOMETHING) VALUES(@ID,@SOMETHING);
    INSERT INTO <LinkedServerName>.<LinkedServerDBName>.<schema>.<table>(ID,SOMETHING) VALUES(@ID, @SOMETHING);

    COMMIT TRANSACTION TRN
END
```

And after that, I would call this sproc with:

```
EXEC SP_MyTest 1, 'Test1'
EXEC SP_MyTest 2, 'Test2'
EXEC SP_MyTest 3, 'Test3'
```